# Create a list of Spatial Polygon dataframe from a list of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial-data-frame

I want Create a list of Spatial Polygon dataframe from a list of dataframe. The list of Spatial polygons is called `list_sp_Tanzania` and the list of dataframe is called `list_df_Tanzania_Modis500`. Each list contains 61 objects and each objects contains several polygons.

```
str(list_df_Tanzania_Modis500)
$ :'data.frame':    30 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ ID        : int [1:30] 296 298 321 323 324 330 331 361 419 453 ...
  ..$ LU_1990   : int [1:30] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
  ..$ LU_2000   : num [1:30] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
  ..$ CHLU_90_00: chr [1:30] "1112" "1112" "1112" "1112" ...
  ..$ LU_2005   : num [1:30] 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 15 ...
  ..$ CHLU_00_05: chr [1:30] "1212" "1212" "1212" "1212" ...
  ..$ Tile      : Factor w/ 1 level "S11_E039": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ UNIQ_ID   : Factor w/ 30 levels "S11_E039_296",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ AREA      : num [1:30] 219337 347133 393961 181875 105137 ...
  ..$ Sour_90_00: chr [1:30] "Modis500_2000" "Modis500_2000" "Modis500_2000" "Modis500_2000" ...
  ..$ Sour_00_05: chr [1:30] "Modis500_2005" "Modis500_2005" "Modis500_2005" "Modis500_2005" ...

str(list_sp_Tanzania)
[[61]]
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 30 
extent      : 38.95413, 39.04577, -11.04522, -10.95469  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Unfortunately, I cannot provide the data with `dput` because they are `s4 objects` and I could not find similar examples. Hope someone can help me somehow though.

Comment: I can't see how your two lists relate, but basically with a data.frame of 30 rows and a SpatialPolygons of 30 features you do SpatialPolygons(df, ps) optionally with arguments to control iD matching. If "list_df_Tanzania_Modis500" is a list, you want df <- list_df_Tanzania_Modis500[[1]]. Similarly for list_sp_Tanzania, but I don't get the [[61]] part?

Comment: The [[61]] part is the 61th spatial polygon object in the list. It says 30 features which means that there are 30 polygons in the 61th spatial polygon object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(x, y, match.ID = F)
}

list_Spdf_Tanzania_Modis500 <- mapply(FUN = fun, 
                                      x = list_sp_Tanzania, 
                                      y = list_df_Tanzania_Modis500)
```